# Changing the Date format in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have the data with one date column in this format: month/day/year (from 1/1/1961 to 12/31/2010), here just a part of it is written.

```
1/1/1961    0.0 
1/2/1961    4.5 
1/3/1961    1.7  
1/4/1961    0.0
```

But I want the date format as:  day.month.year

```
01.01.1961  0.0
02.01.1961  4.5 
03.01.1961  1.7 
04.01.1961  0.0
```

I try this, but without good result:

```
    data$date <- format(as.Date(data$date), "%d.%m.%Y")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> df <- data.frame(date=c("1/1/1961", "1/2/1961", "1/3/1961 " ,"1/4/1961" ), 
+                                         mid=c(0.0,4.5,1.7,0.0))
> df
       date mid
1  1/1/1961 0.0
2  1/2/1961 4.5
3 1/3/1961  1.7
4  1/4/1961 0.0
> df$newdate <- strptime(as.character(df$date), "%d/%m/%Y")
> df$txtdate <- format(df$newdate, "%m.%d.%Y")
> df
       date mid    newdate    txtdate
1  1/1/1961 0.0 1961-01-01 01.01.1961
2  1/2/1961 4.5 1961-02-01 02.01.1961
3 1/3/1961  1.7 1961-03-01 03.01.1961
4  1/4/1961 0.0 1961-04-01 04.01.1961
```

or use:

```
> df <- data.frame(date=c("1/1/1961", "1/2/1961", "1/3/1961 " ,"1/4/1961" ), 
+                                                         mid=c(0.0,4.5,1.7,0.0))
> format(as.Date(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d.%m.%Y")
[1] "01.01.1961" "01.02.1961" "01.03.1961" "01.04.1961"
> format(as.Date(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), "%m.%d.%Y")
[1] "01.01.1961" "02.01.1961" "03.01.1961" "04.01.1961"
```

Comment: Thanks, very good. But I forgot to mention that my data is from 1/1/1961 to 12/31/2010 continuously, and your command works till 12th day of each month. Any idea???

Comment: In `as.Date`, change `format = "%d/%m/%Y"` to `format = "%m/%d/%Y"`

Answer (score 0):

Check the `format` argument in `as.Date`. "`[I]t will try "%Y-%m-%d" then "%Y/%m/%d`". Because your date has a different format (`%m/%d/%Y`), you need to specify the *input format* to make `as.Date` recognize the different time components correctly.

```
date <- as.Date("1/1/1961", format = "%m/%d/%Y")
format(date, "%d.%m.%Y")
# [1] "01.01.1961"
```